# Reemplazar row en tabla html (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table id="Principaltable">
    <tr id="3784"><td><a href='www.eeee.com'></a></td><td>PRUEBA</td></tr> 
</table>
```

Despues tengo en una variable lo siguiente, como ejemplo, y reemplazar el tr anterior completamente:

```
var cad = "<tr id='3784><td><a href='www.ggggg.com'></a></td><td>PRUEBA2</td></tr>";
```

He intentado hacer algo asi, pero no he logrado reemplazarlo:

```
$('#Principaltable').find('id=' + '4416' + '').replaceWith(cad);
```

Pueden guiarme?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes el id, solo tienes que seleccionarlo asi:

```js
var cad = "<tr id='3784><td><a href='www.ggggg.com'></a></td><td>PRUEBA2</td></tr>";


$('#3784').html(cad);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="Principaltable">
    <tr id="3784"><td><a href='www.eeee.com'></a></td><td>PRUEBA</td></tr> 
</table>
```